# Topology induced by convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space. Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are probability measures on $X$ such that $Q$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $P$.

Let $\tau_P$ and $\tau_Q$, respectively, be Ky Fan topology on $X$, which is topology induce by convergence in probability.

Can we compare $\tau_Q$ and $\tau_P$, i.e., which is coarser or finer?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if Q is a.c. w.r.t. P then convergence in probability under P implies it under Q. That should be easy to check since convergence in probability is all about the "bad" set getting small, and small sets under P are small under Q.

Answer (score 2):

If it's comparable and one is "coarser or finer" then the other it should be equal by changing to an equivalent measure.

But it isn't due to the fact, that convergence in probability is metrizable by the metric $d(X,Y) = E[min(1,|X-Y|)]$.

So $X_n \to X$ in probability is the same like $L^1$-convergence of $min(1,|X_n-X|)$ to zero. 
But $L^1$-convergence need not hold for an equivalent measure change so also not convergence in probability.

Comment: In general convergence in $L^1$, or even just membership in $L^1$, is not preserved by changing to an absolutely continuous measure. For example, the measure $\mu$ with density $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ on $(0,1)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$, but $x^{-1/2}$ is in $L^1$ with respect to Lebesgue measure but not with respect to $\mu$. But I'm pretty sure this failure is caused only by *unbounded* functions, which is not relevant to convergence in probability.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit weird, because $\tau_Q$ and $\tau_P$ are not really naturally defined on the same set. $\tau_P$ is naturally defined on functions identified by $P$-a.e. equivalence; $\tau_Q$ is naturally defined on functions identified by $Q$-a.e. equivalence. $P$-a.e. equivalent functions are $Q$-a.e. equivalent but in general the converse is not true.

What is true is that if $X_n \to X$ in probability under $P$ then $X_n \to X$ in probability under $Q$. This is straightforward to prove: suppose $X_n \to X$ under $P$. Let $\epsilon_X>0,\epsilon_P>0$. Take $\delta_P>0$ such that if $P(A)<\delta_P$ then $Q(A)<\epsilon_P$. Then one may take $n$ large enough that $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon_X)<\delta_P$, in which case we have $Q(|X_n-X|>\epsilon_X)<\epsilon_P$. Since $\epsilon_X$ and $\epsilon_P$ were arbitrary, we get the result.

As for comparing the topologies themselves, it is enough to get the result by choosing a single set on which to define $\tau_P,\tau_Q$, and then to prove that both $\tau_P$ and $\tau_Q$ are sequential.

This is where the weirdness comes in: $P$ and $Q$ are both finite, so $\tau_P$ and $\tau_Q$ are both metrizable (and hence sequential) if we identify functions which are equal $P$-a.e. and $Q$-a.e. respectively. (The metric in question can be chosen to be $d(f,g)=\| \min \{ 1,|f-g| \} \|_{L^1}$. Note that this metric makes sense even when $f,g$ are not themselves $L^1$.)

But in general these are different sets of equivalence classes (because there may be $Q$-null sets which are not $P$-null). So it is a little bit more delicate, but still doable, to show that there is a single set that we can put both $\tau_P$ and $\tau_Q$ on such that they are both sequential.

Comment: @tomasz It is a routine result in measure theory, that if $Q$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $P$ then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any set $A$ with $P(A)<\delta$, $Q(A)<\epsilon$. (You might need $P$ to be $\sigma$-finite or so, but in this context $P$ is finite anyway.) This is sometimes even taken as the definition of absolute continuity of measures.

Comment: @tomasz In the paragraph with the metrizability claim, I insisted that the measure $\mu$ be finite.

Comment: @tomasz Yes, you're right about the finiteness, I just checked my real analysis text and it assumes finiteness. It's fine in this context, though, they give the measures being finite. Anyway, I don't understand your point: my point in the second paragraph is that $\tau_Q$ and $\tau_P$ are both metrizable topologies, so it is sufficient to characterize their relative fineness by characterizing whether convergence in one implies convergence in the other. So I did that in the next paragraph.

Comment: @tomasz Oh, I see your concern: their null sets can be different, so their sets $L^1$ can wind up being different. Everything still goes through easily enough though: $\tau_P$ can be taken to be metrizable (identifying functions which are $P$-a.e. equal), and then $\tau_Q$ is pseudometrizable on the same set. No problems actually ensue in the argument, then, but yes, I should correct that point.

Comment: @tomasz How is the answer now?

Comment: Kind of confusing, but I can't think of any way of avoiding it (=confusion) with this kind of question. I think you have touched upon all the important details.